# How to get name of a List<string> from List<List<string>> to bind it dynamically?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, datagrid

I have a dynamic DataGrid in Which 1 column contains ComboBox template. Now I'll get 'N' number of comboboxes. Each ComboBox should have different ItemsSource. how can it be achieved?
My dynamic datagrid has the property ItemsSourceBinding. Now I need to provide a DataContext.BindingName to this property at runtime. How can it be achieved?

```
column.ItemsSourceBinding = new Binding() 
{ 
    Path = new System.Windows.PropertyPath("DataContext." + bindStreamList1),
    RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(DataGrid), 1) 
};
```

In place of `bindStreamList1` I need a name of `List<string>`. it may be from `List<List<string>>` or from `Dictionary<string,List<string>>`

Comment: `List<string>` do not have names associated with them, do you mean to be using Dictionaries? Show us your code.

Comment: column.ItemsSourceBinding = new Binding() { Path = new System.Windows.PropertyPath("DataContext." + bindStreamList1), RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(DataGrid), 1) };
In place of "bindStreamList1" I need a name of List<string>. it may be from List<List<string>> or from Dictionary<string,List<string>>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to get familiar with MVVM pattern. There are tons of tutorials on the web.If you want to have two way binding you should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. You can find yourself also very good tutorials on that. I also would recommend to do your bindings in XAML and not in code behind when ever possible.

Here is an example of what I guess you want:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding }"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableNames}" 
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}"
                                    IsReadOnly="True" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();


    List<MyViewModel1> Items = new List<MyViewModel1>();
    Items.Add(new MyViewModel1() { Name = "Leonardo" , AvailableNames = new List<string>() { "Leonardo", "Michael Angelo" } });
    Items.Add(new MyViewModel1() { Name = "Michael Angelo", AvailableNames = new List<string>() {  "Michael Angelo"} }); // can't make a leonardo out of this item
    Items.Add(new MyViewModel1() { Name = "Master Splinter", AvailableNames = new List<string>() { "Master Splinter", "Jon Skeet" } }); // master stays master PERIOD ..... or become Jon Skeet
    DataContext = Items;

}
```

And the MyViewModel1

```
public class MyViewModel1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<string> _availableNames;
    private string _name;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public List<string> AvailableNames
    {
        get
        {
            return _availableNames;
        }
        set
        {
            _availableNames = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm just read the question again. That's obviously not what you wanted... update follows

Comment: I overworked my answer completely. Now it should fit ;-)

Comment: I changed my code according to this solution a bit and it worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome! Anyway you could upvote my answer instead of saying thx ^^

Comment: I'm new to Stackoverflow so I've less than 15 reputation therefore I can't upvote.

Comment: just joking... ;-)