# How to add dynamic Data in to the datagridviewcombobox column?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am Developing VB.net application.
In that application I take `DataGirdView` to display data.
I took `DataSource` property of the datagridview to display 3 columns' data directly from database.

After those columns I add another `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`. Then I a want to add dynamic the data into that `ComboBoxColumn`.
how to do this?

[image: Click here to see image]

```
Private Function CreatComboBoxWithEnum() As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    Dim combo As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
    Sqlconn = New SqlConnection
    Sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=.\SQLEXPRESS_2005;Initial Catalog=MachineShopScheduling ;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    Dim adpter As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataTable
    Try
        Sqlconn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            Dim val As String = dr.Cells("SrDataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value.ToString
            Query = "select OperationNo from RoutingCalculation where Sr ='" & val & "' "
            COMMAND = New SqlCommand(Query, Sqlconn)
            adpter.SelectCommand = COMMAND
            adpter.Fill(ds)
            combo.DataSource = ds
            combo.DataPropertyName = "OperationNo"
            combo.Name = "OperationNo"
            OperationNo.ValueMember = "OperationNo"
            OperationNo.DisplayMember = "OperationNo"
        Next

        Sqlconn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return combo
End Function
```

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: What do you mean by adding dynamic data to a `ComboBoxColumn`? The `ComboBoxColumn` shows any data which is in its `DataSource`.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is what you are looking for. Read it carefully.

Comment: I added 3 columns from datasource then i add datagridviewcomboboxcolumn and now i want to add the data into combobox column from another table with condition in my query "select op from table_name where sr ='1' "

Comment: Load data into a `DataTable`. Then set the data table as `DataSoure` of your `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`. Also set `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember`. Also set `DataPropertyName` to the field of the data table which is `DataSource` of your `DataGridView` which you want to bind the column to it.

Comment: It's not working @RezaAghaei

Comment: *It's not working* is not a suitable problem description. It doesn't help us to help you.

Comment: Sorry, but I used the same thing which you told me but still comboboxcolumn displayed the empty @RezaAghaei

Comment: It doesn't help too. How can we know how did you load data and how did you set data-bindings. It can be simply reproduced by a few lines of code. So make sure you read about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The first benefit of creating a simple code to reproduce the problem is for you. Usually it helps you to  narrow the problem area and find the problem yourself. Or at least if you couldn't find the problem, it helps us to reproduce the problem using your code and help you to solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get name of a List<string> from List<List<string>> to bind it dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041968/how-to-get-name-of-a-liststring-from-listliststring-to-bind-it-dynamically)

Comment: see this is my code @RezaAghaei

Comment: Vb not supported that class @Mat

Comment: C# also have no "that" class by default. Forwhatever reason i didn't saw that you actually using WinForms and not WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Private Sub load_operationNo()
    Sqlconn = New SqlConnection
    Sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=.\SQLEXPRESS_2005;Initial Catalog=MachineShopScheduling ;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    Try
        op.Name = "OperationNo"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(op)
        Sqlconn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            Dim OPno As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
            With OPno
                Dim adpter As New SqlDataAdapter
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                Dim val As String = dr.Cells("SrDataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value.ToString
                Query = "select OperationNo from RoutingCalculation where Sr = " & val & " order by sr"
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand(Query, Sqlconn)
                    adpter.SelectCommand = cmd
                    adpter.Fill(dt)
                End Using
                .DataSource = dt
                .ValueMember = "OperationNo"
                .DisplayMember = "OperationNo"
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("OperationNo") = OPno
                i = i + 1
            End With
            Next
        Sqlconn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is the code to add dynamically add the data into DatagridViewComboboxColumn

Comment: Add the code to your question. Post Your Answer buttonis just for posting answers. What you have posted should be an edit to your question.